# Some of the webpages of the website are not working in Android in react-naive-webview

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

**-----------------Bug description:-------------------**

**-----------------To Reproduce:-----------------**

**-----------------Dependencies-----------------**

**----------------------------description----------------------------**

i tried many ways to use webview, i also use the iframe tag in webview but nothing happen.